# VS2015 Designer error: The key 'Main.ConnectionString' does not exist in the appSettings configuration section

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Get an error when trying to open some of my forms in the designer.

This is the stack trace:

```
    at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

Here's my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Main.ConnectionString" value="Server=localhost;Database=ACTUAL_DB_NAME_HERE;User ID=ACTUAL_USER;Password=ACTUAL_PASSWORD;"/>
  </appSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think this may be related to data somehow serialized in a form control.

Comment: I've had similar problems when working with database diagrams in 2010. It'd work fine with the config file in most cases (`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnString"].ConnectionString`) but depending on how I ran the code, it'd cause trouble. I had more allround success with adding the string in a settings file and accessing it with `BaseClass.Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnString`. Would that perhaps help you?

Comment: In my case the string (I believe) is being accessed from my ORM library.  I don't anywhere access the string directly from my code--but I do have ORM objects on my form.

Comment: @scotru how did you add your key to app.config? manually by hands?

Comment: Your connection string is in the AppSettings. I believe it should be stored under ConnectionStrings element. Check out  https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I copied and pasted it from a file produced by my ORM (LLBLGen).  It's not actually used in my application--I set the actual connection string at runtime from configuration data stored in an INI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to open your form in designer, your app.config is not accessible to your form. It is because your program is not running and form is not intended to show relevant data from the database. This is by design. It is intended to show just form layout and visuals. So you must not try to open database connections, read files, play video and etc while in design mode.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988745/what-is-the-run-context-for-a-form-opened-in-the-designer-for-a-winforms-applica) for the details.

If the component on this form was written by you, try to wrap the code that breaks the designer in the component `Load` event in the following:

```
if ( this.Site == null || !this.Site.DesignMode )
{
... // code that breaks the designer
}
```

**EDIT:** Best practice is to store connection strings in specialized section of app.config. [Here is a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055349/what-is-the-difference-between-connectionstrings-and-appsettings) of this.

Comment: Thanks--I was able to trace this down to a data-aware user control that tried to load data at designtime.  I used the strategy you describe on the control and was able to resolve the issue.